# Can we protect a Domain Model from JSON request not creating a DTO object?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-data

For Web/JSON requests  we don't want to expose the entire domain model to the client.  One of the patterns in this case is using a DTO object and then mapping from domain models to DTOs and back.

The example of DTO is LoginUserDTO that is used in JSON requests:

```
public class LoginUserDTO {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

In addition we have a User POJO annotated as Entity with much more properties.  By using LoginUserDTO we protect other fields of the User entity to be updated

However, having multiple DTOs creates code repetition, would it be possible to avoid this repetition? I am using Spring/Hibernate with Spring Data

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely more code, but it will be worth it in the end. If your service is supposed to "own" its data, it should keep it abstracted from end-users. This means giving clients an API. The API has DTOs and Functions. The data layer has its own Models.

Just think if you wanted to start storing data as a time-series. You wouldn't want all clients to have to know that. Or you want to add or remove fields from a table. Or you want write a fancy join that makes it so you have to query less often. All of these things would mean changing your user-facing API if you did not have two sets of objects.

So in addition to having a DTO and a Model, you will also need a Converter! Lucky for you, `Spring` is ready with a pattern/class to use.

```
import com.example.dto.LoginUserDto;
import com.example.model.LoginUser;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class LoginUserDtoToLoginUserConverter
    implements Converter <LoginUserDto, LoginUser> {

  @Override
  public LoginUser convert(LoginUserDto source) {
    if (source == null) {
      return null;
    }
    LoginUser target = new LoginUser();
    target.setEmail(source.getEmail());
    target.setPassword(source.getPassword());
    return target;
  }
}
```

Fun isn't over yet though! You still have to convert Model objects **back** into DTOs when returning objects to the client. Yay!

```
import com.example.dto.LoginUserDto;
import com.example.model.LoginUser;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class LoginUserToLoginUserDtoConverter
    implements Converter <LoginUser, LoginUserDto> {

  @Override
  public LoginUserDto convert(LoginUser source) {
    if (source == null) {
      return null;
    }
    LoginUserDto target = new LoginUserDto();
    target.setEmail(source.getEmail());
    target.setPassword(source.getPassword());
    return target;
  }
}
```

Beautiful isn't it. So much waste. But no, there really is no other way to go about this. You either store your "wire" objects or you convert them.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

*It is not so a smart solution but somebody might find useful for specific situations.*

You may write JSON classes and extend them from POJO classes. For instance;

```
public class LoginUserAsJSON {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}

public class LoginUserAsPOJO extends LoginUserAsJSON {
    private int userId;
    private Date loginTime;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is up to design choice, both is technically equal but as i mentioned in example above, extending JSON class from POJO class is reasonable.